# Missing provisioning profiles in Xamarin Studio

Tags: ios, provisioning-profile, xamarin-studio

In organizer I have 2 valid profiles with app id like "QQWWEE.*" and "QQWWEE.com.org.appname", 
but in Xamarin studio visible only one profile "QQWWEE.*".

App id in project equals to  "QQWWEE.com.org.appname".

Why I can't choose "QQWWEE.com.org.appname" profile?

Comment: Im wondering about ur profile name..

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Bundle identifier must be like "com.org.appname", not "QQWWEE.com.org.appname"